# from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font ImportError: cannot import name Style

Tags: python, openpyxl

While running a python code, I am facing the following error :

```
sbassi-mbpro:FacebookEventScraper-master sbassi$ python facebook_event_scraper.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebook_event_scraper.py", line 13, in <module>
    from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font
ImportError: cannot import name Style

python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/a4373fb5b471/openpyxl/styles/?at=default) for openpyxl.styles, the [__init__.py](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/a4373fb5b471f8dd6000b06e675cf37fe6a0ccad/openpyxl/styles/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) file doesn't define any name: `Style`.

Perhaps you were looking for `NamedStyle` instead?

Comment: The `Style` class is no longer used. Please use the correct documentation for the version of openpyxl you're using.

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) for Style and `NamedStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> from openpyxl.styles import Font, NamedStyle
```

[Automate the Boring Stuff Edited materials](https://www.reddit.com/r/inventwithpython/comments/8ykq1i/automate_the_boring_stuff_with_python_corrections/)